# Recover object lazy-loading the containing file

Tags: c++, lazy-loading, boost-serialization

I'm using a binary file to recover an object using `boost::binary_iarchive_ia` but it is too heavy (18GB) and that object loads the entire file to memory. Is there a way to read the file by parts (a lazy load) to avoid the memory use?

What I have:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename); 
boost::archive::binary_iarchive_ia(ifs);
MyObject obj; 
ia >> obj;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us how your program loads the file. `std::ifstream` does *not* load the entire file into memory by itself.

Comment: Use seekg to set the file position.

Comment: That code by itself does not read any data.

Comment: What is `boost::archive::binary_iarchive_ia`?

Comment: @NeilKirk function from boost library that loads the file and recovers the object serialized in the binary.

Comment: Software design is hard work.  You can't make computers do impossible things; how much you need to hold in memory is entirely dependent on your problem.  If you want to sum all the numbers in a file, you only need as much memory as to hold the accumulator for the sum.  As your problems get more complicated, how much you hold in memory can vary; *you need to state your specific requirements*.  I'll mention that if you really need random access to all the information in a file, consider looking into [Memory Mapped Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)...it's not serialization.

Comment: That is probably the problem. I don't know much boost though.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

@cmaster got really close to an approach that can workm but he accidentally put the problem upside down.

The raw file was never the issue (it was streaming all along).

The problem is that deserialization tries to put the data all in memory (the vector, e.g.). So the only real solutions would be to

- is to put this data into a (shared?) memory map. You can use the allocators from Boost Interprocess to help you achieve this. This is a lot of effort, but relatively straight forward, conceptually.
- one could modify the deserialization code to convert to a different on-disk format on the fly (instead of inserting into e.g. that vector), which would then allow `mmap` as cmaster suggested it.

  In other words, you'd "canibalize" the boost serialization implementation to migrate the data away from boost serialization towards a raw binary format that affords using it directly in mapped memory.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my oversight :-) I'll leave it for reference, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mmap()` to map the file into your address space. With that, it doesn't matter that the file is too large because the kernel knows that any data in the mapped region is just a copy of the file on the hard disk. Consequently, it does not even need to swap the data out when it needs the memory for something else. The kernel will just lazily load the parts of the file that you need as you touch them, which is especially good if you don't need everything in the file.

The nice thing about `mmap()` is that you have the entire file contents accessible as a huge `char` array, which is quite convenient for many use cases. The only precondition that must be met is that your process runs as a 64 bit process, otherwise your virtual address space will be too small to fit the file into it.

Comment: Oops. You accidentally put the problem upside down. The raw file was never the issue (it was streaming all along). The problem is that deserialization tries to put the data all in memory (the vector, e.g.). So the only  real solution is to put this data into a (shared?) memory map. *OR* one could modify the deserialization code to convert to a different on-disk format on the fly, which will allow the `mmap` approach as you suggested it.